# Does having a pruned node reduce its network score?

Tags: full-node, connection, pruning

My node's network score (revealed by `getnetworkinfo`) is very low (<75). Most of the time there are no peers with incoming connections connected to the node. Is this because I'm running a pruned node? Would that reduce the network score?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### What's the meaning of the score in `getnetworkinfo`?

When you look up `getnetworkinfo` in the Bitcoin [Developer Reference](https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-reference#getnetworkinfo), it says about `score`:

> The number of incoming connections during the uptime of this node that have used this address in their `version` message

If I understand that correctly, this means that the score is the number of times *incoming* connections have been established with your node since it started.

### Network services and pruning

Nodes on the network announce the services they offer by setting their network services flags.

There are currently five flags in use:

- `NODE_NETWORK (1)`
- `NODE_GETUTXOS (2)`
- `NODE_BLOOM (4)`
- `NODE_WITNESS (8)`
- `NODE_XTHIN (16)`

Out of these, `NODE_NETWORK` indicates that your node will serve historical blocks. Currently there is no way to announce that you can only serve a subset of all blocks, so just like nodes that cannot serve blocks at all, pruning nodes don't advertise `NODE_NETWORK`.

### Pruning nodes don't get referred by DNS seeders

This has a direct effect on the number of incoming connections pruning nodes get, as DNS seeders only refer nodes that advertise `NODE_NETWORK` when new nodes request additional peers to connect to. This means that pruning nodes only get incoming connections when they are referred by non-DNS seeder nodes.